# Only the UWP project is running

Tags: xaml, uwp, uno-platform

It doesn't work if I try to add multiple pages to UNO SOLUTION. There are a lot of mistakes coming out. Only the UWP project is running. [One of the mistakes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0C5n.png).

[LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33oFt.png)

Comment: Could you please tell me what version of your Visual Studio?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2019, but I also tried it in Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `Page (Uno Platform UWP)` then copy the body.
I also fixed the error in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

To fix `InitializeComponent` error in Uno, you could refer to the following steps that are from the official document.

You could build your project once, close the solution and reopen it. It is also important to note that Uno uses a multi-project structure, for which each project has to be build individually for errors to disapear from the **Error List** window (notice the Project column values).

In order to clear the **Error List** window, build the whole solution completely once. Thereafter, build a specific project and prefer the use of the Output tool window (in the menu **View** -> **Output**), taking build messages by order of appearance.

Comment: First of all, it is recommended that you could use the **uno-check** command-line tool to troubleshoot your environment. Please search “Troubleshoot your environment with uno-check” in chrome browser, you will find the related official documents.

Comment: One thing I have to say is that I copied the XAML pages from another project to the uno project, does it make a difference?

Comment: It should work.  When I copy XAML from another project I will create the page first in the current project, then copy and paste only the body portion of the XAML.  For me- I found that I am less likely to get a reference wrong.

Comment: One other thought- Have you tried to create create a blank UNO project and run it- maybe put a simple textblock in it with hello world?  That would also help you verify your environment is set up correctly.